# How to detect if the current app was installed as a Google Play Experiment?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, event-tracking, install-referrer

We would like to know which experiment the user installed(if any) and associate this with our own tracking data logged within the app. This raises the question:

**From inside the currently running app, how is it possible to retrieve and analyse any Google Play Experiment data about which experiment was installed?**

Additional info:
We are successfully using the INSTALL_REFERRER intent to track referral information from the Google Play store, however this does not provide information about experiment data.

Comment: Did you ever figure something out for this?